# Error (?) in Day counting PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-math

```
<?php
$date1 = "2002-1-1";
$date2 = "2021-12-31";
$deff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$daycount = $deff / (60 * 60 * 24);
echo $daycount;
?>
```

Why the answer is 7304 instead of 7300 as I am trying to calculate the number of days for 20 years?

Please help.

Comment: Aren't there 4 leap days in that period?

Comment: The inclusion of leap years?

Comment: 7304 is correct answer,i checked with datediff in sql :)

Comment: Thanks friends. Yes the problem is of leap days. is there any way to get it exactly 7300 without manipulating later? I mean without counting the leap days.

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime for this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2002-1-1");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2021-12-31");
$interval  = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed   = $interval->format('%a days');
echo $elapsed;
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ifrhkZ)

**Reference**

- [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Comment: I guess this means the output is correct.

Comment: Sorry Mr. John Conde. It still returns 7304 days.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. That is how many days there are between the two days. Don't forget about leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, the answer is:

> From and including: Tuesday, 1 January 2002
>
> To, but not including : Friday, 31 December 2021
>
> It is 7304 days from the start date to the end date, but not including the end date.

You forgot to add the **leap years**. That is the **four extra days**!!!